# Update records that only have 1 instance on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update records in my documents table from another source.

> Documents

```
Name         , Account Number, Date of birth
S MHLONGO   ,  00000         ,16/12/1986
O CHUMU     ,  00000         ,12/12/1986
V MBONANE   ,  00000         ,09/12/1986
```

> Client

```
Name, Account Number, Date of birth
    S MHLONGO   ,  33178         ,16/12/1986
    S MHLONGO   ,  33682         ,16/12/1986
    O CHUMU     ,  32892         ,16/12/1986
    V MBONANE   ,  52162         ,16/12/1986
```

As you can see, I don't have an account number to link to in `Documents`, but what I can use is the Name and the Date of birth. However , there could be two or more S MHLONGO that are born on the same day. So I need to run an update statement that will search the Name and the Date of birth in `client` and if it only has 1 entry (And only 1 entry in Client) that matched the `Documents` column `Name and date of birth` to update that those records in `Documents`

```
Example
```

> Documents

```
    Name        , Account Number, Date of birth
    O CHUMU     ,  32892         ,16/12/1986
    V MBONANE   ,  52162         ,16/12/1986
```

I know its a bit risky, i just want to know if it can be done and how would the script look like?

I have backups of all DB's :-)

Comment: use a sub query in a WHERE CLAUSE, do WHERE ...AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENT C WHERE C.Name = D.Name AND C.DOB = D.DOB) = 1  -  check it gives the correct records first in a select, then you could add it to a CTE, and just update over the CTE, or do an   - UPDATE...WHERE   --  this is similar to an EXISTS style subquery except in this case your condition is 1 not ANY

Comment: hi @Andrew Deighton, I don't quit understand what you want me to do, could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses `group by` and `join` in the `update` clause:

```
update d 
set account_number = c.account_number
from documents d join
     (select name, date_of_birth, count(*) as cnt,
             min(account_number) as account_number
      from client
      group by name, date_of_birth
      having count(*) = 1
     ) c
     on c.name = d.name and c.date_of_birth = d.date_of_birth;
```

Note the use of `min(account_number)`.  This is fine, because if there is only one account number, then the `min()` (or `max()`) will return it.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, thank you for the response but it does not execute, error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: @user3309798 . . . If the semicolon is causing a problem, then remove it.  SQL Server allows semicolons, but if you are calling in code then there might be an issue.